# PostgreSQL Connection Refused

Tags: postgresql, server, connection, localhost, connection-refused

I have installed PostgreSQL. However everytime I try to connect through PGAdmin or through psql it gives me the below error.

```sql
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) 
      Is  the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and 
      accepting TCP/IP  connections on port 5432? 
could not connect to server: Connection  refused (0x0000274D/10061) 
      Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and 
      accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I checked the `postgresql.conf` file and the line: `listen_addresses = '*'` isn't commented out.

Also this is how my `pg_hba.conf` file is set:

```sql
# IPv4 local connections:
  host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
  host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
```

Can anyone please advise on how I can resolve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: `pg_hba.conf`, not `pg_hba.conf.txt`

Answer (score 8):

Use services  "start -> run -> services.msc" and look for the postgresql-[vers] service.

If it is not running try to start it, if it won't start open the event-viewer (start -> run -> eventvwr) and look for error messages relating to the PostgreSQL service.

Comment: After searching for several answers, this one worked for me! It simply needed to start the application (right click -> start). Then the error is gone!

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was postgres.config.  The port was somehow changed to 5433 in there and I do not remember doing it myself lol.  So make sure your ports are matching up in your project vs postgres.config

Comment: This may have happened if you installed a second version of PostgreSQL while another was already installed (maybe while trying to migrate from version X to version Y), as the second version will see that there is already another PostgreSQL installed and using port 5432, so will automatically set its port to 5433 in `postgres.conf` so that it doesn't conflict with the other PostgreSQL when both servers are running.

Answer (score 0):

`pg_hba.conf.txt` has to be called `pg_hba.conf`.

Beyond this, when you have en authentication error you will get a message similar to:

```
psql -U nonexistent
psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "nonexistent"
```

The error you are getting means most likely that PostgreSQL is not started on this server.

You can start PostgreSQL with:

```
service postgresql start
service postgresql status
```

Comment: `psql -U myuser -d mydatabase` works fine, I did start the service and `status`shows it as *active*. But I still get that `Connection refused` error.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me -

```
In C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\data\postgresql.conf set listen_addresses ='localhost'
```

Then try -

```
pg_ctl -D "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\data" start
```

if already try restarting using pg_ctl

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this.
Open cmd and insert.

```
"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\bin\pg_ctl.exe" runservice -N "postgresql-x64-11" -D "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\data" -w
```

Hit enter...

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.
Remember, whatever comes after -D should be the path to where you installed PostgreSQL, to the data folder, which holds the pg_hba.conf and postgresql.conf files.

```
pg_ctl start -D "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.6/data"
```